# Cloudflare tunnel not able to make a quic connection

Tags: server, cloudflare, tunnel

so I have been trying to set up a cloudflare tunnel for my server. When I tried to run the tunnel it told me that i was using the experimental post-quantum tunnels feature. I was not, so i dont know what it was talking about. Then it gave me a ton of errors:

```
2023-11-27T22:23:30Z ERR Failed to create new quic connection error="failed to dial to edge with quic: timeout: no recent network activity" connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.193
2023-11-27T22:23:30Z INF Retrying connection in up to 2s connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.193
2023-11-27T22:23:37Z ERR Failed to create new quic connection error="failed to dial to edge with quic: timeout: no recent network activity" connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.53
2023-11-27T22:23:37Z INF Retrying connection in up to 4s connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.53
2023-11-27T22:23:44Z ERR Failed to create new quic connection error="failed to dial to edge with quic: timeout: no recent network activity" connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.33
2023-11-27T22:23:44Z INF Retrying connection in up to 8s connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.33
2023-11-27T22:23:51Z ERR Failed to create new quic connection error="failed to dial to edge with quic: timeout: no recent network activity" connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.193
```

This doesn't stop until I end the process.
I'm on endevour os if that helps.